# Service not executing Location Updates

Tags: android, gps, android-service, background-process

I have created an IntentService class which i used to send device data to a web service whether the app is running or is terminated. Here's my code:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class PostMyCoordinatesService extends IntentService implements GPSTracker.GPSUpdateListener,WebService.WebServiceListener {

    GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    DataCacher dataCacher;
    WebService webService;
    private String TAG = Constants.GLOBAL_TAG+"-PostService";
    public static final String SERVICE_NOTIFIER ="<mypackagename>";

    public PostMyCoordinatesService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public PostMyCoordinatesService(){
        super("PostMyCoordinatesService.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG,"HANDLE INTENT IS CALLED!");
        startMyLocationUpdates();

    }


    private void startMyLocationUpdates() {

        //reset location update callbacks if it exists.
        if (gpsTracker != null) {
            gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();
        }

        gpsTracker = null;
        dataCacher  = DataCacher.getInstance();
        if(dataCacher== null)
            dataCacher = new DataCacher(getApplicationContext());

        String seekbarCachedValue = dataCacher.getStringForKey(Constants.KEY_FREQUENCYUPDATES);
        boolean allowGPS = dataCacher.getBooleanForKey(Constants.KEY_ALLOW_DEVICEGPS, false);
        if(allowGPS) {
            gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext(), (Integer.parseInt(seekbarCachedValue) + 60));
            gpsTracker.setOnGPSUpdateListener(this);
            Log.v(TAG,"Starting gps updates.");
        }
        else{
            Log.v(TAG, "Sending gps data was disabled.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        super.stopService(name);
        if (gpsTracker != null) {
            gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();
            Log.v(TAG,"GPS tracking was disabled");
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGPSUpdated(Location updatedLocation) {
        dataCacher = DataCacher.getInstance();
        if (dataCacher == null)
            dataCacher = new DataCacher(getApplicationContext());

        boolean allowGPS = dataCacher.getBooleanForKey(Constants.KEY_ALLOW_DEVICEGPS, false);

        if (allowGPS) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Updating my coordinates>.." + updatedLocation.toString());
            sendMyLocation(updatedLocation);
        }
    }

    private void sendMyLocation(Location location){

        dataCacher = DataCacher.getInstance();
        if(dataCacher==null)
            dataCacher = new DataCacher(getApplicationContext());
        //get phone number
        String phoneNumber = dataCacher.getUserPhone();

        String url =Constants.URL_POST_DEVICE_LOCATION+
                phoneNumber+"/"+
                location.getLatitude()+"/"+
                location.getLongitude()+"/"+
                location.getSpeed()+"/"+
                location.getBearing()+"/"+
                location.getAltitude();

        Log.v(TAG,">>update my coordinates url: "+url);

        webService = new WebService(url,this);
        webService.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void didReceiveData(String data, WebService caller) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Coordinate Update Service: " + data);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(SERVICE_NOTIFIER));

    }

    @Override
    public void didReceiveError(String errorMessage) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Coordinate Update Service ERROR: "+errorMessage);
    }
}
```

my logcat shows that my handle intent has been called:

```
08-27 14:03:01.989  26460-26534/? V/Test-PostService﹕ HANDLE INTENT IS CALLED!
08-27 14:03:02.003  26460-26534/? V/Test-PostService﹕ Starting gps updates.
```

But the callback method `onGPSUpdated(Location updatedLocation)` wasn't called. I am certain of my GPSTracker class' callbacks for I have used it on my previous projects. What could be the cause of this? What is the more efficient way to send updates to web service for both my app's running and terminated status. I am new to Service by the way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Here's my GPSTracker class.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

    public interface GPSUpdateListener {
        void onGPSUpdated(Location updatedLocation);
    }

    String TAG = Constants.GLOBAL_TAG+"-GPSTracker";

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; //meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000*60; //default 60 secs

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;


    //snarf added variables
    private static GPSTracker trackerInstance;

    //snarf added methods
    private GPSUpdateListener listener;
    public void setOnGPSUpdateListener(GPSUpdateListener updateListener){
        listener = updateListener;
    }
    public static GPSTracker getTrackerInstance(){
        return trackerInstance;
    }

    public GPSTracker(Context context, int updateIntervalSeconds) {
        this.mContext = context;
        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = updateIntervalSeconds * 1000;

        Log.v(TAG,"starting location updates every "+MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES+ " milliseconds.");
        getLocation();
        trackerInstance =this;
    }
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return location;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
        getLatitude();
        getLongitude();


        if(listener!=null)
         listener.onGPSUpdated(location);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            Log.v(TAG,"Stopped gps updates!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: best way extends `service` instead of `IntentService`

Comment: how do i implement my code on service?

Comment: post your GPSTracker.!

Comment: posted it. I think maybe because i extended GPSTracker with service?

Comment: where is onLocationChanged of LocationListener

Comment: but i can't see your class in que.!!

Comment: may be listener is null. best way to send brodcast when location changed